# Place Label under each point from spaceBetweenPoints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I'm using a custom UIView for creating this control with 4 hotspots with the same space between the points. I'm trying to create for labels exactly under the points and it seems like the first label is correctly aligned, but i cant seem to figure out why all of them aren't correct?

Here you see the space between each point and the radius on the points.

```
customSlider?.spaceBetweenPoints = 95
customSlider?.radiusPoint = 5
```

illustration at the moment:

[image]

```
    customSlider?.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width-335)/2, 20, 335, 34)

    for var i = 0;i<4;i++
    {
        var xPointSpace = 95
        var xPos = xPointSpace * i
        var xSpace = (self.frame.width-335)/2
        var xWidth = Int(xSpace) + xPos
        var xFloat = CGFloat(xWidth)


        var textLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(xFloat, 34, 30, 21))
        textLabel.text = "lol"
        textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12)
        self.addSubview(textLabel)

    }
```

adding the labels:

Comment: Maybe by adding `i*5` at `xPos`, seems that your `radiusPoint` is messing.

Comment: okay i've added that but it still misses distance. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

customSlider?.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.width-335)/2, 20, 335, 34)

```
for var i = 0;i<4;i++
{
    var xPointSpace = 95
    var radiusPoint = 5
    var xPos = (xPointSpace + radiusPoint * 2)* i 
    var xSpace = customSlider?.frame.origin.x
    var xWidth = xSpace + xPos
    var xFloat = CGFloat(xWidth)


    var textLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(xFloat, 34, 30, 21))
    textLabel.text = "lol"
    textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12)
    self.addSubview(textLabel)

}
```